# Validating groups of checkboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have groups of checkboxes like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name"checkboxes1" value="#value1">
<input type="checkbox" name"checkboxes1" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" name"checkboxes1" value="#value3">

<input type="checkbox" name"checkboxes2" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" name"checkboxes2" value="#value2">
<input type="checkbox" name"checkboxes2" value="#value3">
```

Is there an easy way in jquery to return a value of 1 for each group of checkboxes, if both of the following conditions apply:

- All of the checkboxes in the group that start with a # in their value are checked
- All of the checkboxes in the group that don't start with a # in their value are not checked

Note: the names of the checkboxes are dynamically generated, so there could be any number in a group, any number of groups and each group could have any name.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the attribute with [[attr^=\#]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) pattern. 
So, you could code something like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="./lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    var checkall = function() {

    var withHashAllChecked = true;
    var withoutHashAllChecked = true;

$("input.cb1:checkbox[value^=#]").each(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        withHashAllChecked = false;
    }
});


$("input.cb1:checkbox:not([value^=#])").each(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        withoutHashAllChecked = false;
    }
});

var result = withHashAllChecked && (!withoutHashAllChecked);
alert(result);

};

$(function() {
    $("input").click(checkall);
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="cb1" type="checkbox" name"checkboxes1" value="#value1">#1</input>
<input class="cb1" type="checkbox" name"checkboxes1" value="value2">2</input>
<input class="cb1" type="checkbox" name"checkboxes1" value="#value3">#3</input>

<input class="cb2" type="checkbox" name"checkboxes2" value="value1">1</input>
<input class="cb2" type="checkbox" name"checkboxes2" value="#value2">#2</input>
<input class="cb2" type="checkbox" name"checkboxes2" value="#value3">#3</input>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT

Updated Full working code. This is only checking checkboxes with class cb1, but just to give you an idea how to achieve. I must apologize that the original code has some problem that I didnt check it. Anyway, I try the above code and it should be fine (should you modify the jquery directory reference).

Comment: I can't seem to get it working with that code - always returns false. Could I set CONTEXT as the name of the current checkbox?

Comment: I've managed to get it working perfectly using your code and tweaking it a bit to use the name, not class - you did all the leg work though! :) thanks very much...

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked = $('input:checkbox:checked[name=checkboxes1][value^=#]').length;
var notchecked = $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)[name=checkboxes1][value^=#]').length;
```

Comment: I've managed to select the checkboxes with value that begin with # using your code above (but you don't need to include the input at the start), but how do i return 1 if the group of checkboxes with the same name are all checked if their value starts with #, and 0 if they are not? Thanks..

Comment: You just need to add to the selector a search for the name attribute with the value you want and then figure out if it found any results.

Comment: would it be possible to insert the name, say, as an array? As i won't know the name of the checkboxes beforehand. So make a unique array for all checkbox names, that have at least one value that starts with #?

Thanks :)